# How to use a group by function in a select Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query and i need to check the min(temp) from a vehicle in every ten minute. So i have to write a sub query in a select query.

```
select vehicle_no,
location,
temp,
(select min(temp)
 from vehicle_mst
 where company_id = 100
 and vehicle_no = 'abcd'
 and sys_time between to_date('20/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') 
              and to_date('20/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') +10/1440 min_temp,
company_name
from vehicle_mst
where company_id = 100
and vehicle_no = 'abcd'
and sys_time between to_date('20/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') 
             and to_date('21/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')


select vehicle_no,
location,
temp,company_name
from vehicle_mst
where company_id = 100
and vehicle_no = 'abcd'
and sys_time between to_date('20/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') 
             and to_date('21/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
```

this query is working find but if i write sub query for this then this is not working.

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirement is. Are you asking for the details of the vehicle now and the minimum temperature during the previous 10 minutes ? It would be good to see a sample of data as I suspect an analytic function would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple group by clause like below -

```
select vehicle_no
      ,location
      ,temp
      ,to_date(sys_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') +10/1440
      ,min(temp) min_temp
      ,company_name
from vehicle_mst
where company_id = 100
and vehicle_no = 'abcd'
and sys_time between to_date('20/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
                 and to_date('20/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
group by vehicle_no
        ,location
        ,temp
        ,company_name
        ,to_date(sys_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') +10/1440
```

Though I have not tried it, but this should work.

Comment: Can you please explain what this bit here is all about: `to_date(sys_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') +10/1440`?

Comment: There are 1440 minutes in a day so it should just group it by every 10 minutes. As OP also tried it this way.

Comment: I am not sure that expression will result in a separate group for each 10 minute period.  Rows with `sys_time` values of 10:31:00, 10:32:00, and 10:33:00 will get group by values of 10:41:00, 10:42:00, and 10:43:00, respectively.  Three groups.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, Do you think updated answer will work?

Comment: "Work" as in "satisfy the OP's question"?  I can't say because his requirements aren't clear to me.  But no, you still haven't fixed your group by problem.  See the answer by @ThorstenKetter for a better approach.

Comment: sys_time nothing but a column

Comment: select vehicle_no,
location,
temp,company_name
from vehicle_mst
where company_id = 100
and vehicle_no = 'abcd'
and sys_time between to_date('20/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') 
             and to_date('21/09/2019 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi');                                                                         previous this query is there i want to add a column for min(avg) in next 10 min from sys_time which have selected

Comment: @Jagadish, Along with your trial, Please post some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can get ten minutes intervals by formatting the datetime to something like '2019-09-20 09:13' and removing the last digit.

```
select 
  vehicle_no,
  location,
  substr(to_char(sys_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 1, 15) || 'x' as time,
  min(temp) as min_temp
from vehicle_mst
where company_id = 100
and sys_time >= date '2019-09-20' and sys_time < date '2019-09-21'
group by 
  vehicle_no,
  location,
  substr(to_char(sys_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 1, 15)
order by 
  vehicle_no,
  location,
  substr(to_char(sys_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 1, 15);
```

This gets you September 20, 2019 in ten minutes intervals.

If you want this per vehicle and there can be various locations for a vehicle, you'll have to remove `location` from the query.

If you want this for one vehicle only, put it in the where clause (and you could then remove `vehicle_no` from the group by and order by clauses).